# How to get definite integral (Explicit formula?)

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

Please see the below image.
This is a part from Partial Differential equations by Strauss. I was reading a part about how to derive a solution for a Heat (diffusion) equation.

Here is a ODE

> $$
> g'' + 2pg' = 0
> \quad \text{and} \quad
> Q\left( {x,t} \right) = g\left( p \right)
> $$

So, I was able to get
$$
Q\left( {x,t} \right) = g\left( p \right) = {c_1}\int e^{-p^2}dp  + {c_2}
$$
using the integrating factor $\exp\left(\int 2pdp\right) = e^{p^2}$.
Here is my question. The book suddenly says 'We find a completely explicit formula for Q.' and a definite integral form appears as
$$
Q(x,t) = c_1 \int_0^{x/\sqrt {4kt} } e^{ - {p^2}}dp  + c_2
$$

I understand how the implicit form of $Q(x,t)$ is obtained. But, I cannot understand how and why integral interval is suddenly added.
Can you please explain this?

Thanks

Comment: You're new, so you don't yet know.  First:  Write *informative* titles that refer to the specifics of your question.  Second, never post unsearchable pictures of text or equations.  Instead, typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: What is the meaning of $g''$ and $g'$ ? Differentiation wrt which variable(s) ?

Comment: Possibly there is some context in which this is being solved, which results in the formulation using the Heat equation in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

When solving the ODE, you get to the point where you have
$$ 
g'=C_1 e^{-p^2}.
$$
You can then integrate over $[0,p]$ (we introduce a dummy variable $q$) and use the Fundamental Theorem:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^p g'(q)\,dq & = C_1\int_0^pe^{-q^2}dq\\
g(p)&=g(0)+C_1 \int_0^{p} e^{-q^2}dq
\end{align*}
You can then use the fact that $p=\frac{x}{\sqrt{4kt}}$ to get it into the form given. (Technically $g(0)$ can be replaced with an arbitrary constant.)